# Client/Server Communication overwritten

Tags: java, io, server, client

I got a problem solving my Uni's Project. It is about Client/Server Communication and the Exercise is to create a EchoServer repeating every Client's message and sending it straight back to the client. The server closes when the client only sends an empty message. So far my code looks good but my Problem is that for testing purposes I want the conversation between server/client printed out. But I can only see a glimpse of the conversation and then it seems to get "overwritten" by the "Protocol started" message from the start. Here are my codes:

**Server**

```
public class EchoServer {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
        System.out.print("Server läuft");
        Socket s;
        while(true) {
        s = server.accept();
        new EchoProtokoll(s).startProtocol();}
    } catch (NumberFormatException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }}
```

**Protocol**

```
public class EchoProtokoll {
Socket s;
BufferedReader vomClient;
PrintWriter zumClient;
public EchoProtokoll(Socket s) {
    this.s = s;
    try {
        zumClient = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),false);
 //I also tried true as parameter
        vomClient = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void startProtocol() {
    System.out.print("Protokoll gestartet");
    try {
        String client;
        while((client=vomClient.readLine()).length()>0) {
            System.out.print("Client schreibt:"+vomClient.readLine());
            zumClient.println("Echo: "+client);
        }

        System.out.print("Protokoll beendet");
            s.close();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Client**

```
public class EchoClient2 extends Thread {
Socket echoSocket;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;
int port;

public EchoClient2(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}
public void run() {
    try {
        echoSocket = new Socket("localhost",port);
        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(),false);
        String nachricht;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        while((nachricht=Aufgabe1.getStr(2)).length()>0) {
            out.println(nachricht);
            System.out.println("Hallo vom Server:"+in.readLine());

        }
        String s="";
        out.println(s);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 }
```

(The method "getStr(int t)" is in another class which was given by the uni and basically randomly generates a string for a certain time. However I doubt there is something wrong with it. In that class 5 clients are generated for parallel access to the servers. I can also post this class here if requested but I highly doubt the problem lies within the Uni's code.)

Edit: The Port is 1025

Comment: `readLine` usually means "read _next_ line". You can't call it two times and expect to receive the same result as you assumed in your `EchoProtokoll` class.

Comment: Ok so basically I can't print it out? Or should I just assign the method to a variable?

Comment: I don't know if you can or not. I'm saying that you should assign result to variable if you want to use it several times.

Comment: Ok changed that, thanks